# How can I store a string with mixed quotes in a Sqlite database using python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a string with mixed quotes that is " and '. I want to store the string in a Text field in a sqlite3 database using python.

Here is the query I'm using and I have a function that executes these queries.

```
"""INSERT INTO SNIPPETS (CONTENT, LANGUAGE, TITLE, BACKGROUND)
                        VALUES("{0}" ,"{1}","{2}", "{3}")
            """.format(content, language, title, background)
```

Something like:

```
with self.connection as conn:
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                try:
                    result = cursor.execute(statement)
                    if(insert_operation):
                        return cursor.lastrowid

                    return result.fetchall()
```

Comment: How about put the string between a pair of triple quotes `'''`

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to make it too complicated. Python `sqlite3` will take care of the quoting for you.

```
statement = 'INSERT INTO SNIPPETS (CONTENT, LANGUAGE, TITLE, BACKGROUND) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'
cursor.execute(statement, (content, language, title, background))
```

Comment: Is there another way? I've put the execute part in a function which I'm calling many times and generating various statements, It would be better not to have to change the function since I'm not passing in the variables but placing them in the string.